# How to catch a FFMPEG exception with subprocess?

Tags: python, exception, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm doing some work on subtitles and some videos have 1 subtitle track, others have 2 subtitle tracks. For those that have 2, I use the 2nd one (index = 1). I'm trying to automate it with python.

For files with with 2 subtitle tracks, I use:

> -vf "subtitles='file.mkv':si=1

and for those with 1 subtitle track, I use:

> -vf "subtitles='file.mkv':si=0

I'm using this code:

```
for mkv in all_mkvs:
    try:
      subprocess.call(f'ffmpeg -i ... -vf "subtitles='file.mkv':si=1 ...')
    except:
      subprocess.call(f'ffmpeg -i ... -vf "subtitles='file.mkv':si=0 ...')
```

But it doesn't seem to care about the exception and just ends the loop whenever it meets a file with 1 subtitle and gives me the error anyway.

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000011af4912880] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.10 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 2.7.2 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000011af4912880] Unable to locate subtitle stream in ./test/349.mkv
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000011af623d880] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args './test/349.mkv:si=1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Operation not permitted
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:3
Conversion failed!
```

As you can see in the error message above, it says: "Error initializing filter .... si=1" because it should be si=0 in the case of that specific file, which is why I added the exception, but it doesn't seem to care about it.

[image]

So I'm trying to catch that error and say "ok, in that case, let's do si=0 instead".

Comment: Is the finished with exit code 0 for the sub-process?  That's kind of odd if it is - normally 0 is a success code??

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing that the "error" ffmpeg gives isn't considered as some kind of system error and is just considered to be a "string" coming from the ffmpeg output?

Comment: Aside: you should use `subprocess.run`, and pass a list instead of a space-separated string.  No reason to start bad habits =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call` returns the returncode, it never raises.

You probably want `check_call`, which will raise a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` on non-zero returncodes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
```

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

```
subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
```

> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute. If check_call() was unable to start the process it will propagate the exception that was raised.

Comment: HI @Cireo - the code's getting a zero return code - is this really going to solve??

Comment: That's a question for the author.  The screenshot is unhelpful as usual, but if I had to guess, the "Process finished with return code 0" refers to the python script they executed, and has nothing to do with the subprocesses.

Comment: Changing call for check_call fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.
In that case, is there any point for ever using "call" over "check_call"?

Comment: In recent versions of python you should use `run` over either of those.  `call` is useful for commands that may or may not succeed, and you don't care, but you want them to run, e.g. `ls backup_dir/TODAY.txt`